# Plotting lines in 3D plots

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to know whether it is possible to change part of the `Style` of a line in a 3D plot, when the line is under a surface, so that it seems obstructed by the surface. Of course I can always work this out using some elementary geometry and `ViewPoint`, but I want to know wether I can make this automatic.

Just to make things more clear, here is an example

```
graph1 = Show[
   Plot3D[{0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.3], Red}, {Opacity[0.3], Blue}}, 
    Mesh -> False], 
   Graphics3D[{{Thick, Line[{{1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}}]}}]];
```

I would like to make, in the example above, the bit of the line that is seen under the plane `z=1` to appear as a dashed line, but the remainder of the line should appear as a solid line.

I tried

```
ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"][graph1]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: The line is always smaller 1 in your plot!?

Comment: Perhaps I did don't explain well. The line will be hidden by the plane ```z=1``` and I want the hidden part to appear as dashed. This will of course depend on the ```ViewPoint``` we set in the options in ```Plot3D```.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `MeshFunction` and `MeshShading`:

```
graph1 = Show[
Plot3D[{0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1,PlotStyle ->{{Opacity[0.3], Red}, {Opacity[0.3], Blue}},Mesh -> False], 
ParametricPlot3D[  {1/2, 1/2, t} , {t, 0, 2} , PlotStyle -> Thick  
, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}
, MeshShading -> {Dashed,Automatic}  ]]
```

[image]